# Firebird ODBC Setup Error

Tags: sql-server, odbc, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a Firebird Database (v2.5) which lives on a server with hostname "FBDEVDB".  I am working on a separate server on which I have installed SQL Server to begin the process of migrating the tables and data into a SQL Server database.

I saw several posts discussing that this can be done using the Import Data feature of SSMS with an ODBC connection to the Firebird DB.  So, I have downloaded and installed the Firebird ODBC Driver 64-Bit.  When I went to configure my DSN I first got an error regarding a missing gds32.dll.  Looking into it further, I realized I needed the fbclient.dll from the Firebird files.  I've copied it over to my SQL Server machine, and now the gds32.dll error is gone, and I can tell it is TRYING to connect to the Firebird instance because if I provide an incorrect username/password it tells me my login is incorrect.

However, when I use a valid login/password, I get the following error message

[image]

I have defined the following fields in the ODBC setup

```
Database: FBDEVDB::C:\Firebird\MYDATABASE.FDB
Client: C:\Temp\fbclient.dll
Database Account: SYSDBA with VALID PASSWORD
```

What am I missing?  I can not seem to find any information on what this error means.

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: The double colon looks suspicious, because normal connection strings are of the form `<server>[/<port>]:<path to db>` (where the port part is optional). What is the exact ODBC configuration you use, see also https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/ for examples (see under ODBC).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I feel stupid.  The double colon was the problem.  I removed it and Connection Successful!  If you add as answer I will accept.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Instead of posting an answer, I have opted to vote to close as a typo.